# error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an error using this library - https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java/blob/master/README.md

```
Graph g = graph("example1").directed().with(node("a").link(node("b")));
        Graphviz.fromGraph(g).width(200).render(Format.PNG).toFile(new File("example/ex1.png"));
```

When I try to surround the second statement with a try/catch, I get these errors along with some other warnings.Please help out!

> Static interface methods are only supported starting with Android N
>   (--min-api 24): guru.nidi.graphviz.attribute.Attributes
>   guru.nidi.graphviz.attribute.Attributes.attr(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.Object) Message{kind=ERROR, text=Static interface methods
>   are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24):
>   guru.nidi.graphviz.attribute.Attributes
>   guru.nidi.graphviz.attribute.Attributes.attr(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.Object), sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>   Failed to process
>   /home/simra/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/guru.nidi/graphviz-java/0.2.3/9b69af16154221cc327d19be9b40a73cb4d3b7cc/graphviz-java-0.2.3.jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wak7O.png)

Comment: If something is not supported till a certain Android version then you need and `if` statement to check the build version of the device first...

Comment: I tried using it too, it's still giving the same errors:                                `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 24) {
            Graph g = graph("example1").directed().with(node("a").link(node("b")));
            try {
                Graphviz.fromGraph(g).width(200).render(Format.PNG).toFile(new File("example/ex1.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }`